# Approach in solving this First Order Nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The 1st Order Nonlinear ODE in question is given by
$$3xy^2y'+3y^3=1$$
I tried separating it but I just couldn't seem to work it out. The integrals just become so complicated when being evaluated. 
What could be another approach to solve this DE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to solve this ODE is to notice that it is separable,
$$
\frac{3y^2y'}{1-3y^3}=\frac1x\implies 1-3y^3=\frac{C}{x^3}.
$$

Comment: I got the general solution in implicit form $\frac{1}{3}\ln\lvert 1-3y^3\rvert = -\ln\lvert x\rvert+C$. I don't know how you got $1-3y^3=\frac{C}{x^3}.$

Comment: Now multiply with $3$, exponentiate, assemble constant and signs into a constant factor.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you can rewrite as

$$x(y^3)'+3x'y^3=1$$ and the LHS is an exact derivative except for the factor $3$.

Then multipying by $x^2$, we have

$$x^3(y^3)'+(x^3)'y^3=(x^3y^3)'=x^2.$$

The rest is easy.

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't follow your line of thought. Is this a general method, or more of just manipulating it?

Answer (score 0):

Given differential equation can be written as $$ \frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x}=\frac{1}{3xy^2} $$ which is [Bernoulli Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) and after the substitution $y^3 = z$ can be converted into first order linear differential equation of the form:
$$ \frac{dz}{dx}+\frac{3z}{x}=\frac{1}{x}. $$
Which can be solved easily by finding integrating factor.

Comment: Isn't the 2nd term $\frac {z^{1/3}}{x}$?

Comment: @PauloVictorio No, firstly multiply $y^2$ both sides and then see the result.